# STM32cubeide with stm32f103c8t6 could not verify ST device

Tags: gdb, stm32, openocd, stm32cubeide, bluepill

I am new to embedded and stm32cubeide, self teaching so I can use it in a group project related to university studies.
After purchasing a "blue pill" from aliexpress, I realized I might of bought a clone chip. I followed the instructions shown [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BUjpxvSQB/error-in-initializing-stlink-device-reason-18-could-not-verify-st-device-abort-connection) (stm32 community site), and I'm still getting an error that the ide cannot verify my ST device.

Here is what I have as output:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00443-gcf12591 (2022-02-09-13:33) [ST Internal]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
swv
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : STLINK V2J39S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.286227
Info : clock speed 4000 kHz
Info : stlink_dap_op_connect(connect)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Info : STM32F103C8Tx.cpu: Cortex-M3 r2p1 processor detected
Info : STM32F103C8Tx.cpu: target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for STM32F103C8Tx.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x20036410
Info : flash size = 128kbytes
Warn : GDB connection 1 on target STM32F103C8Tx.cpu not halted
undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset
O.K.

O.K.:0xE00FFFD0

Info : dropped 'gdb' connection
shutdown command invoked
```

I see in the console "undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset", is this the problem? If so what can I do to solve this? If not, then what do I do other than purchasing another board?

Below is my *test* Debug.cfg, in case I need to change something in there:

```
# This is an genericBoard board with a single STM32F103C8Tx chip
#
# Generated by STM32CubeIDE
# Take care that such file, as generated, may be overridden without any early notice. Please have a look to debug launch configuration setup(s)

source [find interface/stlink-dap.cfg]


set WORKAREASIZE 0x5000

transport select "dapdirect_swd"

set CHIPNAME STM32F103C8Tx
set BOARDNAME genericBoard

# Enable debug when in low power modes
set ENABLE_LOW_POWER 1

# Stop Watchdog counters when halt
set STOP_WATCHDOG 1

# STlink Debug clock frequency
set CLOCK_FREQ 4000

# Reset configuration
# use software system reset if reset done
reset_config none
set CONNECT_UNDER_RESET 0
set CORE_RESET 0

# ACCESS PORT NUMBER
set AP_NUM 0
# GDB PORT
set GDB_PORT 3333



# BCTM CPU variables

source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]

# SWV trace
set USE_SWO 0
set swv_cmd "-protocol uart -output :3344 -traceclk 16000000"
source [find board/swv.tcl]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some FT232 that I had in spare, and I was able to program the chip using the stm32 programmer software and a generated hex file from the ide.

I'll use this method if ever I run into cloned chips and the st link v2 if ever I get a genuine board.

Comment: maybe you should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813942/14720421