# STM32F0308-Discovery Error in initializing ST-LINK device. Reason: No device found on target

Tags: stm32, st-link

I just try to install my code to card and i keep getting this error

```
Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

I just randomly keep randomly keep reverting firmware and updating from cubeide its somehow fixed but after i restart my pc and re-plug the card it giving me the same error. Why this is happening?

Comment: please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813942/14720421 there might be allready code on the board, that disables the SWD after reset. You have to clear the flash to gain debugging access again.